# Android O CALL_STATE broadcast receiver not firing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have a foreground service and register a CALL_STATE receiver there.
It works fine on pre Android O. Another receiver in the service works fine too.
I have removed the intent filter from the manifest.
I have all the correct permissions.

Is there anything else I should be doing?

In Service...

```
private static final String ACTION="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
 registerReceiver(mCallReceiver , new IntentFilter(ACTION));
```

Comment: Just to confirm, do you hold the runtime permission for `READ_PHONE_STATE`, and not just the manifest permission?

Comment: Yes, I do......

Comment: ..I've just double checked and I honestly thought I had the necessary permission. Seems I didnt and now everything works fine.

Comment: OK, glad to see that it's working!

Comment: Actually the "issue" was that I was asking for permission to "CALL PHONE", I thought this gave me access to READ_PHONE_STATE too. I've changed it to ask for "READ_PHONE_STATE" - the permissions text presented to the user is the same, but I now have all the necessary permission.

Comment: Ah, OK, I misunderstood. You might want to convert that last comment into an answer, to benefit others who run across this question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the "issue" was that I was asking for permission to "CALL PHONE", I thought this gave me access to READ_PHONE_STATE too. I've changed it to ask for "READ_PHONE_STATE" - the permissions text presented to the user is the same, but I now have all the necessary permission.